# update query not working on edit account page

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a edit account page that pre loads the users account info and they can edit it if they want.  The code is not showing any errors but it always runs the catch and doesn't save the new data.  Here is the code.  So basically the query is not updating the record.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"     AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EditAccount.aspx.cs" Inherits="EditAccount" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">


<table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                    User Information : Edit
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text="Address : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text="City : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text="State : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddState" OnSelectedIndexChanged="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="State" DataValueField="State" Height="17px" Width="148px" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [State] FROM [States]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblZip" runat="server" Text="Zip : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone# : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="E-Mail : "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style ="width: 14%">

                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</asp:Content>
```

and here is the C# code behind.  the Submit button click is the query not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class EditAccount : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {

            txtUsername.Text = Session["New"].ToString();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string getfirstname = "select UserFirstName from Users where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand firstcmd = new OleDbCommand(getfirstname, conn);
            string firstName = firstcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            txtFirstName.Text = firstName;

            string getlastname = "select UserLastName from Users where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand lastcmd = new OleDbCommand(getlastname, conn);
            string LastName = lastcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            txtLastName.Text = LastName;

            string getaddress = "select ShipAddress from Users where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand addresscmd = new OleDbCommand(getaddress, conn);
            string Address = addresscmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = Address;

            string getcity = "select ShipCity from Users where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand citycmd = new OleDbCommand(getcity, conn);
            string City = citycmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            txtCity.Text = City;

            string getstate = "select ShipState from Users where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand statecmd = new OleDbCommand(getstate, conn);
            string State = statecmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            ddState.Text = State;

            string getzip = "select ShipZip from Users where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand zipcmd = new OleDbCommand(getzip, conn);
            string Zip = zipcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            txtZip.Text = Zip;

            string getphone = "select UserPhone from Users where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand phonecmd = new OleDbCommand(getphone, conn);
            string Phone = phonecmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            txtPhone.Text = Phone;

            string getemail = "select UserEmail from Users where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand emailcmd = new OleDbCommand(getemail, conn);
            string Email = emailcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = Email;
            conn.Close();

            Response.Write(txtUsername.Text);

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
        }
    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = '" + Server.MapPath("App_Data/WSC_DB.mdb") + "'; Persist Security Info=False");

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Users set UserFirstName = @FirstName, UserLastName = @LastName, ShipAddress = @Address, ShipCity = @City, ShipState = @State, ShipZip = @Zip, UserPhone = @Phone, UserEmail = @Email, UserName = @Username where UserName = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", ddState.SelectedValue.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                Response.Redirect("ViewAccount.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ViewAccount.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the **exception message** ?

Comment: The reason it isn't showing you any errors is that you are catching the exceptions, using `Response.Write` to write them in a way that may not even show up on your page (try surrounding the message with `<div>{ex.ToString}</div>`, and then proceeding as though nothing ever happened.

Comment: It's not giving me any exception message, but as soon as the code gets to Response.Redirect(ViewAccount.aspx) it goes to the catch

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868882/update-query-not-working-on-edit-account-page/21869395#comment33110706_21868882)

> It's not giving me any exception message, but as soon as the code gets to Response.Redirect(ViewAccount.aspx) it goes to the catch

Looks like this is the error you got

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

Try to change this

```
Response.Redirect("ViewAccount.aspx");
```

to this

```
Response.Redirect("ViewAccount.aspx", false);
```

and move that line out of `using` block

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Users set UserFirstName = @FirstName, UserLastName = @LastName, ShipAddress = @Address, ShipCity = @City, ShipState = @State, ShipZip = @Zip, UserPhone = @Phone, UserEmail = @Email, UserName = @Username where UserName = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", ddState.SelectedValue.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}

Response.Redirect("ViewAccount.aspx", false);
```